# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'expr' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, meanjs

I'm building a project with the meanjs stack. I want to use an angular lib that I found to make my selectors to look like the ones that bootstrap provides us.

https://github.com/joaoneto/angular-bootstrap-select (This is the library)

I added it in my bower.json and it's installed correctly inside my public/lib folder. After that I included it together with the bootstrap-select.js in my configuration.

/rootFolder/config/env/all.js:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    app: {
        title: 'MyProject',
        description: 'my project description',
        keywords: 'MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, Node.js'
    },
    port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
    templateEngine: 'swig',
    sessionSecret: 'MEAN',
    sessionCollection: 'sessions',
    assets: {
        lib: {
            css: [
                'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
                'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css',
            ],
            js: [
                'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
                'public/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js', 
                'public/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js', 
                'public/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js', 
                'public/lib/angular-touch/angular-touch.js', 
                'public/lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js', 
                'public/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
                'public/lib/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js',
                'public/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
                'public/lib/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.js',
                'public/lib/angular-bootstrap-select/build/angular-bootstrap-select.js'
            ]
        },
        css: [
            'public/modules/**/css/*.css',
            'public/dist/css/*.css'
        ],
        js: [
            'public/config.js',
            'public/application.js',
            'public/modules/*/*.js',
            'public/modules/*/*[!tests]*/*.js'
        ],
        tests: [
            'public/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'public/modules/*/tests/*.js'
        ]
    }
};
```

I'm getting the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'expr' of undefined

I entered inside the lib and I'm getting the error here:

```
$.expr[':'].icontains = function(obj, index, meta) {
    return $(obj).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(meta[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
```

Any help will be so appreciated thank you!

Comment: could you solve the problem? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @JamesCazzetta I finally abandoned this task. So if you finally solve it It could be great if you can post your answer here ;)